# ajax event not posting data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a 2 ajax call. First ajax call populates the dropdown box which works correctly, bu the second ajax call uses change event function. Whenever the dynamically populated item from the dropdown is clicked it lists the products details with image.

In below code the change function triggers becos it alerts the data item selected.  but the problem starts inside the ajax i guess. so i am not getting the result(product details)

Problem: it donot list the products

also how to use var_dump($_POST) to check name1 is passed correctly

second ajax code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#name").on('change',function (e) { 
    var name1 = this.value;
    alert("name1 = " + name1);
    $.ajax ({
        data:{name1: name1},
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'dataprod.php',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);

            $('.products-wrp').html('');
            $('.products-wrp').hide();
            $('.products-wrp').html(response);
            $('.products-wrp').show();            
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

dataprod.php

```
<?php
$name1 = $_POST['name1'];
$results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT product_name, product_desc, product_code,  
product_image, product_price FROM products_list where product_name='$name1'");

$products_list =  '<ul id ="products_list" class="products-wrp">';
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$products_list .= <<<EOT
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>{$row["product_name"]}</h4>
<div>
<img src="images/{$row["product_image"]}" height="62" width="62">
</div>
<div>Price : {$currency} {$row["product_price"]}<div>
</form>
</li>
EOT;
}
$products_list .= '</ul></div>';
echo $products_list;
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Didn't you post this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327551/change-event-not-firing-on-ajax-loaded-elements

Comment: You should add `error: function(e) { alert(e) }` to your ajax call.

Comment: It's ironic that the "Try this" first posted answer got an upvote, and the other "try this" with more code got downvoted (none of them were mine, I might add) and the other one also contains `'/dataprod.php'` with the slash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
...
url: '/dataprod.php'
...
```

Comment: The question here is "why" should they "Try this code"?

Comment: and how do you know that that file is located in their root?